# Make added hspace disappear if at a line break

Tags: math-mode, spacing, line-breaking

Consider the following example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\pagestyle{showlocs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\hspace*{8cm} text text text $\{ x\in X \, \vert \, \allowbreak x > 0\}$

\hspace*{8cm} text text text $\{ x\in X \, \vert \allowbreak x > 0\}$

\end{document}
```

As we can see in the first example the `\,` is still present after the `\vert` and the `\vert` looks slightly indented from the right.

Is there a method we can use such that `\,` is only inserted if a line break does *not* immediately follow?

I've been attempting to use  `\discretionary{}{}{\,}` but that fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you add the `\,` after the `\allowbreak`?

Comment: Ahh, that was easy. Write an answer. It of course disappears at the start of the line

Comment: You surely know that `\,|\,` is not the right way for this and that `\mid` is the right symbol; since it is a relation symbol it *does* allow breaks.

Comment: @egreg you also know that `\mid` is not the right symbol as it cannot scale, thus confusing the users who have to use a different construction if the fences are large. `\mid` therefore cannot be build into automated fencing macros like `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX`

Comment: @daleif With that macro users won't see or type `\mid`, nor `\,\vert\,`, I guess. Adding explicit thin spaces is wrong except for the `\middle` case, that's special. There are `\bigm`, `\Bigm` and so on for getting the correct spacing which, by the way, is `\nonscript\;`

Comment: @egreg  Exactly. I was just using a very simple MWE. I'm trying to promote the this set syntax: `\Set{ x \in X \given -1 < x < 1}` where `\given` then hides all the confusing stuff: `\nonscript\:\delimsize\vert\allowbreak\nonscript\:\mathopen{}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the thin space after the `\allowbreak` will not stick it at the end of the line, while absorbing it at the beginning of a line.  When in the middle of a line, it will be visibly there.  In the 3rd paragraph of my MWE, I show it in the middle of a line (with the thin space after the `\vert`), and at the end of the line (where the `\,` gets absorbed at the beginning of the next line).

For reference, the first two paragraphs are from your MWE.  In the 1st paragraph, the thin space is not absorbed at the end of the line.  In the 2nd paragraph, the thin space after the `\vert` is omitted all together.

As egreg points out in his comment, `\mid` is his recommended replacement for `\,\vert\,`.  Of course, the space added of `\mid` is different than a thin space.  For comparison, I show the use of `\mid` in the 4th paragraph

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\pagestyle{showlocs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\hspace*{8cm} text text text $\{ x\in X \, \vert \, \allowbreak x > 0\}$

\hspace*{8cm} text text text $\{ x\in X \, \vert \allowbreak x > 0\}$

\makebox[8cm]{$\{ x\in X \, \vert \allowbreak \, x > 0\}$} 
  text text text $\{ x\in X \, \vert \allowbreak \, x > 0\}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: When TeX decides for a line break, it throws away discardable items that follow the chosen break point, in this case the penalty. Kerns (like `\,`) are discardable.